# Building a Pyramid of Circles - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, sprite-kit

I am looking to draw a pyramid of circles using SpriteKit and SwiftUI, like the diagram below

```
  o
 o o
o o o
```

I am using the below set of loops to try and generate them, however I am having two issues with them. Firstly I want it to appear the other way around, in my head it is upside down.

Also I want to add specific spacing between each of the circles rather than having them touch on every level; hence the spacer variable at the top.

```
let spacer: Int = 40

for i in 0...7 {
    for j in 0...i {

        let x = Int(W) - ((i * radius) + radius) + (j * diameter)
        let y = ((i * radius * 2) - radius) + side

        addNode(posX: Double(x), posY: Double(y))
    }
}
```

- addNode(posX, posY) just creates a circle at the two coords provided

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix the formula?

Comment: You do not need sprite for this! SwiftUI is working fine

Comment: @swiftPunk im using the nodes as objects in a game, that benefit from physics bodies, so as far as I'm aware SwiftUI won't work?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you are trying but I did not worked with sprite!

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var heightOfPyramid: Int = 3
    @State private var spacing: CGFloat = 10.0
    @State private var sizeOfCircle: CGFloat = 25.0

    var body: some View {
        
        Spacer()
        
        VStack(spacing: spacing) {

            ForEach(0...heightOfPyramid, id:\.self) { outSideIndex in
                
                HStack(spacing: spacing) {

                    ForEach(0..<outSideIndex, id:\.self) { index in
                        
                        Circle()
                            .frame(width: sizeOfCircle, height: sizeOfCircle)
                        
                    }

                }
                
            }
            
        }
        .animation(Animation.interactiveSpring(), value: heightOfPyramid)
        .shadow(radius: 10.0)
        
        Spacer()
        
        VStack {
            
            HStack {
                Text("heightOfPyramid:")
                Slider(value: Binding(get: { return Double(heightOfPyramid) }, set: { newValue in heightOfPyramid = Int(newValue) }), in: 0.0...10.0)
            }
            
            HStack {
                Text("sizeOfCircle:")
                Slider(value: $sizeOfCircle, in: 0.0...50.0)
            }
            
            HStack {
                Text("spacing:")
                Slider(value: $spacing, in: 0.0...50.0)
            }
            
            
        }
        .padding()

    }
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: This would be fine if I didn't need the physics bodies of the circles as mentioned in my comment above

Comment: It cab be implemented! I personally did not worked with sprite until now! PS: If you are going to use SwiftUI as a drawing tool! my answer is for you, if you are drawing in sprite and you want make use of it in SwiftUI then that is other case. for me is a little unclear what you need! If you working with sprite then u could be able to draw the thing I did.